# [SQUID-6.1]: Setup Squid ipv4 to ipv6 proxy

Tags: proxy, ipv6, squid

I'm trying to setup a squid proxy that will accept multiple inbound connections on one IPv4 across a range of ports, and for each port connection to connect out on a unique IPv6 address.

I can actually connect to proxy but when I check my IP on a browser it says
the IPv4 address of the server.

Please help me to understand the issue

There is my squid.conf (ubuntu 22)

```
access_log none
cache_store_log none
cache deny all

forwarded_for delete
via off
follow_x_forwarded_for allow localhost
follow_x_forwarded_for deny all
request_header_access X-Forwarded-For deny all
request_header_access Authorization allow all
request_header_access Proxy-Authorization allow all
request_header_access Cache-Control allow all
request_header_access Content-Length allow all
request_header_access Content-Type allow all
request_header_access Date allow all
request_header_access Host allow all
request_header_access If-Modified-Since allow all
request_header_access Pragma allow all
request_header_access Accept allow all
request_header_access Accept-Charset allow all
request_header_access Accept-Encoding allow all
request_header_access Accept-Language allow all
request_header_access Connection allow all
request_header_access All deny all


acl to_ipv6 dst ipv6
http_access deny all !to_ipv6

acl allow_net src 1.1.1.1
http_access allow allow_net

# Common settings
acl SSL_ports port 443
acl Safe_ports port 80 # http
acl Safe_ports port 21 # ftp
acl Safe_ports port 443 # https
acl Safe_ports port 70 # gopher
acl Safe_ports port 210 # wais
acl Safe_ports port 1025-65535 # unregistered ports
acl Safe_ports port 280 # http-mgmt
acl Safe_ports port 488 # gss-http
acl Safe_ports port 591 # filemaker
acl Safe_ports port 777 # multiling http

http_access deny !Safe_ports

acl CONNECT method CONNECT
http_access deny CONNECT !SSL_ports

http_access allow localhost manager
http_access deny manager

auth_param basic program /usr/local/squid/libexec/basic_ncsa_auth /usr/local/squid/etc/squid.auth

auth_param basic children 5
auth_param basic realm Web-Proxy
auth_param basic credentialsttl 1 minute
auth_param basic casesensitive off

acl db-auth proxy_auth REQUIRED
http_access allow db-auth
http_access allow localhost
http_access deny all

coredump_dir /usr/local/squid/var/cache/squid
unique_hostname V6proxies-Net
visible_hostname V6proxies-Net

http_port 10000
acl p10000 localport 10000
tcp_outgoing_address 2a01:xxxx:f0:90e4:0098:0b13:xxxx:xxxx p10000

#http_port 10001
#acl p10001 localport 10001
#tcp_outgoing_address 2a01:xxxx:f0:b04b:3079:c399:xxxx:xxxx p10001
```

**network**

```
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 96:00:02:62:37:4c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet x.xxx.49.57/32 metric 100 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 83277sec preferred_lft 83277sec
    inet6 2a01:xxxx:f0:90e4:98:b13:6867:4e2a/128 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a01:xxxx:f0:90e4::1/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::xxxx:2ff:fe62:374c/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: welcome, Questions seeking installation, configuration or diagnostic help must include the desired end state, the specific problem or error, sufficient information about the configuration and environment to reproduce it, and attempted solutions. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers and are unlikely to get good answers. Please read carefully step by step [ask]